# How to wrap parent div around float:left child div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the headerLinks div to wrap around both headerLink divs so that I can move the links and edit the margins of the links as a whole. Is this the best way to do it? And if so, how would I fix my code? Thank you in advance.

This is my code:

```css
#header {
  background-color: #EDEDED;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 10px;
}

#headerItems {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#headerName {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #3D3D3B;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.headerLinks {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.headerLink {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  float: right;
}

.headerLink a {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #E1E1E1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul id="headerItems">
    <li id="headerName">My name</li>
    <div id="headerLinks">
      <li class="headerLink"><a href="" target="_blank">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="headerLink"><a href="" target="_blank">Link 2</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the links on the right should be in a `ul`.

And I'm pretty sure you don't want the links reversing the order,
So you will need to add `float:right` on the parent (headerLinks), and float left on the `li`s

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {margin: 0;}
#header {
  background-color: #EDEDED;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#headerName {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #3D3D3B;
  font-size: 28px;
}
#headerLinks {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
}
.headerLink {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
.headerLink a {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #E1E1E1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <span id="headerName">My name</span>
    <ul id="headerLinks">
      <li class="headerLink"><a href="" target="_blank">Link 1</a></li>
      <li class="headerLink"><a href="" target="_blank">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to make a dropdown menu, you will nest another `ul` inside the `li`